# Label cells within Bigtable

Tags: bigtable

How to label cell value with two labels ? Is it possible or is there a limitation. For example label the cell value with x,y.

How to label cell value with two labels ? Is it possible or is there a limitation. For example label the cell value with x,y.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, the labels can only have a single value defined by the label filter param. So it's not something you can add to the cell and use it to filter later.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-filters#apply-label